# Why does Feistel encryption algorithm encode half block every time?

Tags: cryptography, encryption

Why does Feistel encryption algorithm  encode half block every time? What would happen if the entire block is encrypted in each step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  Some of the block is used as the input to the F function, and the rest is modified. Those can't overlap.  If you wanted to modify all of the block, there wouldn't be any input to the F function.

You might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher#Unbalanced_Feistel_cipher